# BeanFieldGroup create nested entities

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

```
@Entity
public class Document {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="paper", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<DocumentAuthor> authors;
}

@Entity
public class DocumentAuthor {
    @Column(name="order")
    @NotNull
    private Integer order;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="account", columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Account account;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="document", columnDefinition = "integer")
    private Document document;
}
@Entity
public class Account {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="account", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<DocumentAuthor> papers;
}
```

above my entities that i want to use with beanfieldgroup. If i edit/create a document, i want to add one or more authors (Account) and set an order for these. How can i dynamically create these "JoinTable" with BeanFieldGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Viritin add-on](https://vaadin.com/addon/viritin) contains many handy helpers to edit this kind of relations. The optimal solution is always domain specific. If you want to create the authors inline you can use ElementCollectionField ([example](https://github.com/mstahv/jpa-addressbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/PhoneBookEntryForm.java#L48-L49)). If you just want your users to choose from an existing set of referred entities, you can use MultiSelectTable (example) or [CheckBoxGroup](https://github.com/viritin/viritin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/viritin/fields/CheckBoxGroup.java).

None of the fields in Viritin support ordering out of the box, but at least adding simple up-down arrows should be rather easy.